# Outer Join acting like an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Working on this bug, and I need another pair of eyes.
This query should take all records from `Period_Matrix` whether or not it's in `Sales_Matrix`, but it's not, Instead, it's only taking record where both are there, which is an inner join, not outer. This is on SQL Server
Like I said, spent an hour on this, need a fresh perspective.

```
select 
   *
from Period_Matrix PM 
left outer join Sales_Matrix SM_Current 
on PM.current_period = SM_Current.period 
and PM.Product_Type = SM_Current.Product_Type 
and PM.team_no = SM_Current.team_no
order by period desc, team_no
```

Comment: What happens if you order by "PM.current_period" rather than "period" and "PM.team_no" rather than simply "team_no"?

Comment: You're doing a `left` join on `Sales_Matrix` but the left parameter of the join is `Period_Matrix`. Are you sure you don't want a `right` join?

Comment: They're all left joined to period_matrix on purpose, there are no rights.<br>
Removing the fields from the order by seems to have fixed it. How??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select *
from Period_Matrix PM left outer join
     Sales_Matrix SM_Current 
     on PM.current_period = SM_Current.period and
        PM.Product_Type = SM_Current.Product_Type and
        PM.team_no = SM_Current.team_no
order by period desc, team_no;
```

This should be doing a bona fide left join.  The question is:  Are you seeing the results you expect?

Well, first you have duplicate column names.  More importantly, you have columns from the *second* table in the `order by`.  `NULL` values don't always order the way you want them to.  I would suggest:

```
select PM.*, SM_Current.??, . . .
from Period_Matrix PM left outer join
     Sales_Matrix SM_Current 
     on PM.current_period = SM_Current.period and
        PM.Product_Type = SM_Current.Product_Type and
        PM.team_no = SM_Current.team_no
order by PM.current_period desc, PM.team_no;
```

I am guessing this will fix your problem.

The `SELECT` is saying to list out all the columns from the second table, explicitly, to avoid duplicates and redundancy.